# How to trace the line where a tx failed in truffle tests?

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, truffle-test

I know about 0x's [sol-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@0x/sol-compiler) and [sol-trace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@0x/sol-trace). I used them before and they do exactly what I'm looking for, but these modules bring significant overhead when used with truffle. Check out [this file](https://github.com/sablierhq/sablier/blob/f988edabf25f77cca4ce2627bb4eda04aefd96f1/packages/protocol/truffle-config.js) to see why.

Is there a native way to do this with truffle?

Answer (score 0):

Truffle has a `debug` command that lets you move through your source code. It is not quite easy to use, but still, it is a debug option.
See https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/debugging-your-contracts

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't get you to the exact line of code where a bug occurs.